# Poynting vector flux on a closed surface

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, poynting-vector

What does the flux of the Poynting vector through a closed surface represent?

I know that the flux of the Poynting vector on a certain surface represents the power flowing through it. But if the surface is closed (and so it contains a certain volume $V$), what does it represent? Is it the power radiated by $V$, the power received (entering) by $V$, the difference between them?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the typical convention where the flux in question is calculated as 
$$ \iint\limits_{\partial V} \vec{S} ·d\vec{A}$$
where $\vec{S}$ is the Poynting vector, the integral is over the closed boundary $\partial V$ of $V$ and $d\vec{A}$ is along the outward normal vector, by Poynting's theorem, it represents the electromagnetic energy flowing out of $V$ per unit time.

Comment: So is it simply the power that comes out of the surface? For instance: if V has an input port to which I send 3 W, and an output port from which 2 W go out, is that integral equal to 2W?

Comment: Yes, but crucially, it only includes "electromagnetic" power. For instance, heat flow is not included.

in the case you describe, assuming the powers you are talking about are "electromagnetic" in nature, the integral would actually be 2 W - 3 W = -1 W. You can think of each port as having an associated Poynting vector. The net power flowing out of $V$ is $-1 W$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much

Comment: In what form is the energy flow?